# Cannot select and copy certain text within iPhone iOS 16 apps

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, copy-paste

Until recently, I believe any text displayed on my iPhone 13 within an app could be selected and copied. Recently, certain text cannot be selected with press and hold or double tap. For example. I am using the chat feature in a customer service app. I sent a message to support and, after sending, tried to copy the text of my message, but I am unable to select or copy any text, including the message I sent. What settings do I need to change to ensure that all displayed text can be selected and copied, as was previously possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer of the app controls this and if it’s a web view, you might be able to add an extension to strip whatever JavaScript they are using to protect things    but that only works for me in safari - not embedded web browsers delivered in an app.

There is no OS / system setting to disable pasteboard copy and selection operations.

---

If you were to make a [screen shot of the chat](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289), new iOS features make that [live text selectable](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-live-text-iphcf0b71b0e/ios), so you might need that system feature if the developer will not make their apps accessible to screen reading and copy operations.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to understand. Is this a new update to iOS that gives the power to app developers to prevent selection of text? I don't recall this being the case previously. Seems to add a fair amount of inconvenience to us users.

Comment: No, the ability to control select is a very old macOS and iOS feature of the SDK. What changed is the app, not the system @nrp1000